# mjpeg mov created by the newest FFMPEG looks in Windows Media Player like half sized videos

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, windows-media-player, video-playback

I have new version of FFMPEG installed and created mov compressed with mjpeg. Is looks pretty in Afx, Premiere and QucikTime player but it looks like half-sized video in Windows Media Player. There was no such problem in previous version of ffmpeg. Have you any idea how to solve this problem?

```
ffmpeg -i "content/test1080.mov" -sameq -vcodec mjpeg -qmin 1 -qmax 1 -y -s 640x360 -f mov "content/test Big Web.mov"
ffmpeg version 1.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov  5 2012 11:15:58 with gcc 4.4.6 (GCC) 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)
  configuration: --enable-avfilter --enable-libmp3lame --disable-mmx --arch=x86_32 --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --enable-filter=movie --enable-avfilter --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl
  libavutil      51. 73.101 / 51. 73.101
  libavcodec     54. 59.100 / 54. 59.100
  libavformat    54. 29.104 / 54. 29.104
  libavdevice    54.  2.101 / 54.  2.101
  libavfilter     3. 17.100 /  3. 17.100
  libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'content/test1080.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2012-11-08 14:34:46
  Duration: 00:00:03.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 172538 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mjpeg (jpeg / 0x6765706A), yuvj422p, 1920x1080 [SAR 72:72 DAR 16:9], 172517 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-11-08 14:34:46
      handler_name    : Procedura obsługi skrótów danych Apple
      timecode        : 00:00:10;11
    Stream #0:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-11-08 14:34:58
      handler_name    : Procedura obsługi skrótów danych Apple
      timecode        : 00:00:10;11
Output #0, mov, to 'content/test Big Web.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    encoder         : Lavf54.29.104
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mjpeg (jpeg / 0x6765706A), yuvj422p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=1-1, 200 kb/s, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-11-08 14:34:46
      handler_name    : Procedura obsługi skrótów danych Apple
      timecode        : 00:00:10;11
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> mjpeg)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   97 fps= 14 q=1.0 Lsize=   14282kB time=00:00:03.23 bitrate=36149.5kbits/s
video:14280kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.012432%
```

Comment: Are you sure WMP isn't automatically resizing it to fit your display? I don't use Windows, so I can't check what the default behaviour is.

Comment: The problem was with yuvj422p pixel format. When I set -pix_fmt yuvj420p playback in WMP is ok.

Comment: OK. But it doesn't solve my problem. This is where I am: input file is QuickTime compressed with PhotoJpeg. FFMPEG sais pixel format is yuvj422p (the clip was created with Adobe After Effects). This original file plays correctly in Windows Media Player. Now I would like to scale down this clip with FFMPEG.When I keep original pixel format (yuvj422p) in otput file - it has pixelization in Windows Media Player (but only in WMP!). When I set conversion to -pix_fmt yuvj420p WMP plays video correctly but in Afx I can see visible quality loss.

Comment: What I want is to keep pix_fmt yuvj422p and has smooth playback in WMP (this looks like WMP problem not FFMPEG but somehow origianal file plays correctly)